# Reserved Ports in Windows 1809

Tags: networking, windows-10, hyper-v

First time posting here :)

I'm having an issue where some programs can't run on my Windows 10 device.
It seems that there is a lot of reserved TCP ports. I've narrowed some of those reserved ports to Hyper-V. The thing is I can't really change the port used by those programs that fails to run like "Pulse Secure Application Launcher"...

Do you know what could be reserving port ranges like 1540-1639, 2240-2339, 3278-3377, etc... ?

I tried to remove them but I get an error while trying to do so :

```
> netsh int ipv4 delete excludedportrange protocol=tcp startport=1540 numberofports=100
Access is denied.
```

Here's what it looks like when I display excluded port ranges.

```
> netsh int ipv4 show excludedportrange protocol=tcp

Protocol tcp Port Exclusion Ranges

Start Port    End Port
----------    --------
      1540        1639
      1640        1739
      1740        1839
      1840        1939
      1940        2039
      2140        2239
      2240        2339
      2340        2439
      2542        2641
      2677        2776
      2878        2977
      2978        3077
      3078        3177
      3178        3277
      3278        3377
      3378        3477
      3478        3577
      3578        3677
      3678        3777
      3778        3877
     22654       22753
     22754       22853
     50000       50059     *

* - Administered port exclusions.
```

It seems some of them are reserved by Hyper-V like 3278 to 3377 because when I uninstall Hyper-V half of low range reserved ports are removed. However I do need Hyper-V on my computer but each time I try to uninstall / reinstall it, the problem is back again.

Comment: *I would like to know why or how there is port ranges*... This question doesn't make sense. What exactly are you asking?

Comment: Sorry english is not my first language. I'll try to edit to be more clear

Comment: No worries. Your edit is helpful, however, wouldn't it be better to ask how to make use of ports in these reserved ranges instead of why they are reserved?

Comment: The thing is once they are reserved you can't use them except by the program/user which reserved them..

Comment: In the case of reservations made by certain Windows services, that's not true. My point though is that learning why they're reserved doesn't get you an answer you can use to resolve the conflict over reserved ports between your program and whatever has reserved them.

Answer (score 3):

I use next commands to release reserved ports:

```
net stop winnat
net start winnat
```

and this command to check which port ranges currently reserved by system:

```
netsh int ipv4 show excludedportrange protocol=tcp
```